# Intersection of $\emptyset$ and problem about listing definition of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition: $A\cap B=\{x | x\in A \quad \text{and} \quad x\in B\}$

My problem appears when I try to apply this definition to empty sets as following:

$$\emptyset\cap \emptyset=\{x | x\in \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad x\in \emptyset\}$$

Then I evaluate the proposition "$x\in \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad x\in \emptyset$". If $x\in\emptyset$ is false then this has $0$ value.

That is:

$$x\in \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad x\in \emptyset\equiv 0 \wedge 0\equiv 0$$

So what does $\emptyset\cap \emptyset=\{x \;| \; 0 \}$ mean?

In addition, generally, how we should consider the proposition written in the feature of the set $\{x\;|\; PROPOSITION \}$ when it comes proposition takes the value $0$ or $1$?

Comment: That's not how set definitions work

Comment: If $P$ denotes a property of sets and for every set $x$ we have "$P(x)$ is false" (which might correspond with value $0$), then $\{x\mid P(x)\}=\varnothing$ (no set exists that has this property). In your case $P(x)$ is property $x\in\varnothing\wedge x\in\varnothing$, so indeed $P(x)$ is false for every set $x$.

Comment: A tip on readability: spacing in a formula should generally match how it should be parsed; using parentheses helps readability when things don't match up. For example, it would be better to write $$( x\in \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad x\in \emptyset) \equiv 0 \wedge 0\equiv 0$$ Also, in math, $T$ and $F$ or $\top$ and $\bot$ are more common single-symbol names to use when working with propositions; $1$ and $0$ are mostly reserved for working in a numeric context.